# Limitar quantidades de categorias no wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theme, wordpress

Ola, tudo bem.

Estou com uma dúvida aqui e gostaria de um auxilio de vocês

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php $prod_marca = get_field('categoria_e_tags_marca');
        if( $prod_marca ): ?>
        <ul>
            <li><b>Marca</b></li>
            <?php foreach( $prod_marca as $term ): ?>
              <li class="text-small-lista"><?php echo $term->name; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Neste código eu puxo um campo do Advanced Custom Field que me retorna várias categorias, porém não quero printar todas as categorias, quero limitar a quantidade de categorias que serão printadas.

Hoje o layout quebra porque aparece em um bloco 5 categorias e em outro bloco 20 categorias.

Queria limitar a 5 categorias apenas, ou seja, não importa quantas categorias forem setadas no admin, só irá printar 5.

Será que conseguir deixar claro o auxílio que preciso?

Desde já agradeço a todos que poderem me ajudar com essa dúvida.

Att...

Comment: Um amigo me passou a seguinte informação que resolveu meu problema `<?php foreach( array_slice($prod_marca, 0, 5) as $term ): ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o array_slice para extrair uma parcela de uma array, no exemplo a seguir, vc vai percorrer o array na posição 0 até chegar na posição 5

```
foreach( array_slice($prod_marca, 0, 5) as $term ): ?>
     <li class="text-small-lista"><?php echo $term->name; ?></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Dica:
Se vc estiver criando categorias de posts e/ou posts personalizados, o correto é trabalhar com taxynomy no wordpress e não criar uma campo personalizado para simular uma categoria no post.

Documentação ensinando a criar uma taxynomia: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Tutorial Basico passo a passo de como criar uma taxynomia em um post personalizado: https://blog.mxcursos.com/taxonomia-no-wordpress/

Comment: Obrigado Glaydson pela resposta... funcionou corretamente